# Android deep redirect failure on rotating screen

Tags: java, android

I'm searching for a solution on a warning I receive when rotating the screen. Whenever I rotate it I get logcat warning "deep redirect failure". I searched online but couldn't find much on what it actually means. The app works fine but I don't want to leave it like that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Build Date: 07/31/12 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/master
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036 +  NOTHING
06-29 19:13:57.293  27769-27769/com.example.application D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-29 19:13:57.313  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011c => 0x0a090014, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x00000000
06-29 19:13:57.313  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011d => 0x0a090012, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x00000000
06-29 19:14:09.715  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011c => 0x0a090014, defStyleAttr=0x00000000, defStyleRes=0x00000000, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:09.715  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011d => 0x0a090012, defStyleAttr=0x00000000, defStyleRes=0x00000000, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:09.715  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011c => 0x0a090014, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:09.715  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011d => 0x0a090012, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:09.765  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011e => 0x0a090039, defStyleAttr=0x01010394, defStyleRes=0x01030127, style=0x01030127
06-29 19:14:09.765  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011f => 0x0a09003a, defStyleAttr=0x01010394, defStyleRes=0x01030127, style=0x01030127
06-29 19:14:09.765  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011c => 0x0a090014, defStyleAttr=0x00000000, defStyleRes=0x00000000, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:09.765  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011d => 0x0a090012, defStyleAttr=0x00000000, defStyleRes=0x00000000, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:09.775  27769-27769/com.example.application D/Logged﹕ true
06-29 19:14:09.845  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011c => 0x0a090014, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x00000000
06-29 19:14:09.845  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011d => 0x0a090012, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x00000000
06-29 19:14:11.156  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011c => 0x0a090014, defStyleAttr=0x00000000, defStyleRes=0x00000000, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:11.156  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011d => 0x0a090012, defStyleAttr=0x00000000, defStyleRes=0x00000000, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:11.156  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011c => 0x0a090014, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:11.156  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011d => 0x0a090012, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:11.206  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011e => 0x0a090039, defStyleAttr=0x01010394, defStyleRes=0x01030127, style=0x01030127
06-29 19:14:11.206  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011f => 0x0a09003a, defStyleAttr=0x01010394, defStyleRes=0x01030127, style=0x01030127
06-29 19:14:11.206  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011c => 0x0a090014, defStyleAttr=0x00000000, defStyleRes=0x00000000, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:11.206  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011d => 0x0a090012, defStyleAttr=0x00000000, defStyleRes=0x00000000, style=0x01030123
06-29 19:14:11.216  27769-27769/com.example.application D/Logged﹕ true
06-29 19:14:11.326  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011c => 0x0a090014, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x00000000
06-29 19:14:11.326  27769-27769/com.example.application W/asset﹕ deep redirect failure from 0x0103011d => 0x0a090012, defStyleAttr=0x010102ce, defStyleRes=0x01030123, style=0x00000000
```

This is my onCreate function

```
Boolean logged = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
            logged = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("LOGIN_VAL");
        } else {
            logged = false;
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                logged = extras.getBoolean("Logged");
            }
        }

        Log.d("Logged", logged.toString());

        if(logged == false)
        {
            loginUser();
        }
    }
```

How can I pinpoint the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I searched over the Internet and I haven't find an answer for you problem so I don't really know how to fix that but I have an idea..

Maybe try to go to -- > Eclipse --> Project --> Clean..

:)